# how to update values in activity from another activity in android?

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, adapter

I have an Activity called FeedActivity which has arraylist of some data. An adapter names as FeedAdapter in separate class is also there to fill the listview in FeedActivity. FeedDetailsActivity which shows details of feed(listview single row data) when we click on listview row from FeedAdapter. 
What I want to do is that I am passing the arraylist to the FeedAdpter's constructor from FeedActivity and in this way a new copy of arraylist is being created in FeedAdapter class. and when I go to FeedDetails from FeedAdapter I show all the information of that particular feed(listview single row data). Now user can change data in feed details from FeedDetailActivity. 
My problem is that when I change data in FeedDetailActivity then it must reflect in the listview of FeedActivity. but the list is being populated with data from the duplicate arraylist of FeedAdapter. How can I do this . Please let me know as I have tried alot to do this.

Comment: if I use a static arraylist then this would be much easier but for that is not a good approach as it consumes large memory while having a large static ararylist

Comment: Sir, your explanation is quite elaborate, but posting your codes will let people help you based on your code..

Answer (score 0):

It is more of a Java logic question than being specific to Android.

What I understood is that you want to update the previous Activity from the current Activity.

You could create callback methods, or use Intents, or make you array static (then it'll be accessible form both classes).

Another way is to kill the previous activity and start that activity afresh passing your updated ArrayList as extra data.

Comment: What I did 
1. making static arraylist (works but consumes lot of memory)
2. Can kill and restart the activity again but then I will have to again call the server to fetch data and also will have to manage listview position.
3. startActivityForResult from adaptor but this is being called instantly not when I return to my main activity

Comment: I've list other ways too. Best way is to create callback methods.

Comment: that make sense. let me try with it

Answer (score 0):

You can use Observer Design pattern (best for this type of scenario) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern.

Otherwise more likely use [LocalBroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) example [here](http://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam?recipeId=4547)